# What calculation is implied by this Gaussian term?

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation-maximization, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'd appreciate this community's help in understanding the calculation implied by the Gaussian term in this equation:

$$w_{ik} = \alpha_{k} \mathcal{N}( \mathbf{y}_i | \mathbf{X}_i \mathbf{\beta}_k , \sigma^2_k \mathbf{I} )$$

***Source:** "[Probabilistic Curve-Aligned Clustering and Prediction with Mixture Models](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/216300654_Probabilistic_Curve-Aligned_Clustering_and_Prediction_with_Mixture_Models)", by Scott Gaffney. From equation (3.9) on PDF page 56/printed page 37.*

The equation arises in an expectation-maximization algorithm for clustering curves. A **curve** consists of—in a typical case—the positions in two or three dimensions at which an object has been observed over time. A **cluster** is characterized by a set of polynomial equations, one per dimension, with time as the independent variable.

The equation gives the probability that curve $i$ is a member of cluster $k$.

Within the Gaussian term, $\mathbf{y}_i$ is a matrix of observed positions. For example, if we had five observations in three dimensions, $\mathbf{y}_i$ would be a 5 × 3 matrix.

The matrix product $\mathbf{X}_i \mathbf{\beta}_k$ represents evaluating the cluster's polynomials at the times of the curve's observations. The product has the same number of rows and columns as $\mathbf{y}_i$.

I think I grasp the relevance of the Gaussian distribution here: at a point in time, it allows us to quantify the closeness of the curve's observed position to the position calculated via the cluster's polynomials, thus giving us insight into the likelihood the curve is a member of the cluster.

And I'm comfortable with the notion of a Gaussian distribution whose mean is a *single* polynomial-calculated position (having however many dimensions), and with computing that distribution's PDF at a *single* observed position.

However, the Gaussian term references not individual positions, but the *multiple* observed and polynomial-calculated positions, both structured as matrices. *So, what computation is the term implying?*

My best guess is that I'm to consider a Gaussian distribution for each polynomial-calculated position, with that position as its mean; compute the PDF at the corresponding observed position; and multiply the PDF values together. But that's very much a guess!